# Run a windows service as AD user (currently logged in with)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, active-directory, windows-services

I have an AWS EC2 Windows instance which is already connected to an AD server. I log in to the Windows instance by the AD admin user then I need to run a Windows service (Written in C#). The service must be run as the current AD user. My problem is every time I re-install the service I have to set the `Log On As` user of the service. So, I was curious if it's possible to set the service to run under the current AD user automatically then I wouldn't need to repeat the process every time.

Comment: What exactly is the "current user"? The service may run with no interactive user logged in.

Comment: The current user is the AD admin user `admin@<aws.ad.server>`. Actually, the service needs admin-level permissions to run. It manages the AD users who access an FSX filesystem.